# Installed huge font package, now text won’t display

Tags: windows-7, fonts

I installed something between 3,000 and 4,000 fonts onto my computer earlier today. However now, no google chrome pages will load, program fonts/text will not appear 9as you may see in the images below if I can get the page to actually allow me to upload them... if not I will have to use links...) and I do not have a windows disk to attempt to reinstall windows with. Some things however, such as internet explorer, file navigations, and icons do actually have some functioning text, even though it was somehow set to a completely different font. Please help as soon as possible, because it is becoming nearly impossible for me to use my computer without the text or functioning web browser. I would also like to add that only about 50 of the 3k-4k fonts have actually appeared in my fonts folder.

*ADDITION* Whenever my mouse sits anywhere on the screen, no matter what, it will continuously flash the loading circle on and off, without stopping.

Photo links, I could not get the upload image working:

Example of program missing text:
[image: bla]

System information:
[image: bla]

Comment: Was there any clash between the fonts you installed and the ones you already had?

Comment: Perhaps if you use system restore, the fonts would be removed?

Comment: I believe that when I was installing there were a few that I already had, other than that, I don't think so...

Comment: Yeah, it’s generally not a good idea to install fonts you got “somewhere”. It’s also not a good idea to have 4000 fonts installed.

Comment: You appear to have created 2 accounts. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Press Win+R and type in the following

```
control fonts
```

On the left side click on **Font Settings**. After that click on the **Restore default font settings**

**Method 2**

Press Windows Key + R and type in the following

```
rstrui.exe
```

Click next and select a point before you installed all those fonts. Click next and follow the on screen instructions. If you're on your laptop make sure to have the battery inserted and charged and make sure it is connected to the AC power. You don't want a power loss during a system recovery. After that fonts should be removed.

It is not a good idea to have that many fonts installed on your system, install just the ones you need one by one. You can also try CCleaner and clean the font cache and see if it helps.